# How to get Document Library Value for 'Populate a Microsoft Word Template'

Tags: ms-word, powerapps, power-automate

I want to 'populate a microsoft word document template'  dynamically. I almost done but I'm missing the 'Document Library' Value. How do I get this value in a flow?

In this screenshot I manually put the correct value (which I found by chance) in there.

[image]

I tried getting the right value with this step:

[image]

Outputs in this case would be 'account' or 'shared documents' for example.

The returned body contains an 'UniqueId' but sadly this value does not work for 'Populate a Microsoft Word Template'.

Comment: Are you actually able to populate a template based on a schema?

Comment: @SeaDude Yes. Fill Location, Document Library and File static so you can fill your presets. Fill them -> click on the 3 points in the top right corner -> Peek code -> You can see the text you filled for the presets and you can see some IDs. Now your dynamic file schema looks similar to this: { "123456789": "Your text for one preset", "-123456789": "Your text for the next preset", ... }